# Do WD HDDs work with Linux?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, compatibility

I'm planning on my first pc build and have decided to use a WD Blue WD10EZEX 1TB as hard drive. I've heard someone say that this drive had an encryption that made it useless with Linux. Is this true, and in  that case, how do you decrypt it? Is it worth buying it for a Linux build, and if not: which HDD should I buy instead?

Comment: Drive encryption does not prevent repartitioning and reformatting of the drive.   Encryption only protects the contents inside the partition that is encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a standard SATA drive.  There should be no reason you can't.  Hard drives don't come encrypted out of the box.

Comment: [Some do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption), but you can still use them.

Comment: Yeah, there's SED's out there, but even then, most people don't know to set the KEK to use it, and it performs as a standard drive as all the decryption/encryption is done on-board, transparent to the OS :)